# How to serve my VueJs application with apache?

Tags: apache, vue.js

I built the application with command:

```
npm run build
```

and I uploaded the content in 'dist' folder on a VM (Debian OS) of my university at which I connected via SSH.

I have to serve the application with Apache but I don't know how to do.

More over there are several public services running, so I don't want to break anything.

Thank you for help.

Comment: hope this helps: https://alvarez-michael-joseph.medium.com/how-to-deploy-a-vue-js-webpack-application-to-apache-tomcat-7770ad609f1f

Comment: I think I don't have enough permissions, because I can't navigate to apache directory.